# Can ReactiveCocoa be used with pure c++ ViewModels?

Tags: c++, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

The motivation is the sharing of view models across platforms (Android, Windows Phone).

For example, consider:

```
RAC(self.nameField,text) = RACObserve(self.viewModel, playerName);
```

What if `self.viewModel` is pure C++(11)?

Obviously C++ doesn't have properties, but perhaps it can be made to work somehow? Or is ReactiveCocoa coupled to Objective-C on both sides (naturally being coupled on the UI side is no big deal, as some other binding mechanism would have to be used for the relevant environment regardless).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obviously C++ doesn't have properties, but perhaps it can be made to work somehow?

Wrap your C++ objects in Objective-C wrappers.

> Or is ReactiveCocoa coupled to Objective-C on both sides (naturally being coupled on the UI side is no big deal, as some other binding mechanism would have to be used for the relevant environment regardless).

There are some UI-specific extensions to UIKit and AppKit in ReactiveCocoa, but the core of the library has no dependency on or knowledge of "the UI side" at all, but most of the functionality in ReactiveCocoa 2.x relies on runtime features in Objective-C objects.

`RACObserve()` is just a macro for a method that ultimately ends up calling `-[NSObject rac_observeKeyPath:options:observer:block:]`, which itself uses an Objective-C-specific technology called [Key Value Observing](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/). C++ objects don't support KVO out of the box, so they don't work out of the box with `RACObserve()`.

Answer (score 2):

ReactiveCocoa relies on a Cocoa style implementation of the observer pattern, which in turn relies on the dynamic-dispatch nature of Objective-C.

In Cocoa observers work by performing isa-swizzling of a class (reassigning the class pointer to a runtime generated subclass. The sub-class overrides the setter method to notify an associated reference of observers when a property changes.

As C++ uses static/vtable style of dispatch, this style of method interception isn't supported. Therefore ReactiveCocoa observers won't work. So the answer is essentially no, ReactiveCocoa won't work for pure C++ classes, although the underlying principles could be applied, or you might look for an Rx library for C++.

Interestingly, Swift defaults also to static/vtable dispatch (though supports dynamic dispatch if you extend NSObject or use the @objc decoration). Here's a[n article describing another style of observer for Swift](http://www.merowing.info/2014/07/implementing-observable-in-swift/).

Comment: +1 Regarding a C++ Rx library, I'm not sure how that would help. I'm more interested in the *binding* aspect of the library than its "reactive" aspect (chaining events etc). In light of that, I don't see how something like `Rx.cpp` would be of much help unfortunately. It seems `boost:signal` would work just as well for this scenario, which is not as well as ReactiveCocoa which generates events automatically for changing viewmodel properties, binds view properties to the viewmodel with `RAC`, and comes with built-in signals for UI controls such as `rac_textSignal`.

Comment: `boost::signal` is an implementation of signals and slots ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_and_slots ), which is unrelated to the Signals/Observables in ReactiveCocoa and other Rx frameworks.

Comment: As Cocoa-style observers rely on method interception, perhaps the next best way to achieve interception in C++ would be with an AOP library. Due do the static-dispatch nature of C++ this works using a pre-processor to  produce new source prior to compilation. . but this way you could have the same kind of transparent binding. Although Cococa doesn't use AOP and AOP introduces the concept of 'pointcuts' on top of method interception, its the method interception part that is important, and a good way to get this in C++ is with AOP.

Comment: ps: Above comment I meant if you wanted to 'roll-your-own' solution that works like Cocoa observers. . You could use AOP to get interception. . not sure if C++ Rx libs already use precompilation or something to get this transparent-style binding.

Comment: @OhadSchneider Yeah, I figured you wouldn't have time to go all the way and roll your own, though I got to thinking how transparent binding could work in C++, and thought it would make for an interesting side-discussion/comment.